Matplotlib Stackplot Gradient
Is it possible to fill the "Odds" area with a gradient from left (green) to right (transparent)? I would like to do this in a plot to indicate uncertainty.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
y2 = [0, 4, 2, 6, 8]
y3 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

y = np.vstack([y1, y2, y3])

labels = ["Fibonacci ", "Evens", "Odds"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, labels=labels)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(x, y)
plt.show()




Based on this answer, you could do:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
y2 = [0, 4, 2, 6, 8]
y3 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

y = np.vstack([y1, y2, y3])

labels = ["Fibonacci ", "Evens", "Odds"]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
stacks = ax.stackplot(x, y1, y2, y3, labels=labels)
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

xlim = ax.get_xlim()
ylim = ax.get_ylim()

stacks[-1].set_facecolor([1, 1, 1, 0])  # set original face color to transparent

verts = np.vstack([p.vertices for p in stacks[-1].get_paths()])
gradient = ax.imshow(
    np.linspace(0, 1, 256).reshape(1, -1), 
    cmap='Greens_r',  # reversed Green colormap
    aspect='auto',
    extent=[verts[:, 0].min(), verts[:, 0].max(), verts[:, 1].min(), verts[:, 1].max()]
)

gradient.set_clip_path(stacks[-1].get_paths()[0], transform=ax.transData)
ax.set_xlim(xlim)
ax.set_ylim(ylim)

fig.show()


